# Latency in IMap.get(key) when the object being retrieved is heavy

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

we have a map of custom object key to custom value Object(complex Object). We set the in-memory-format as OBJECT. But IMap.get is taking more time to get the value when the retrieved object size is big. We cannot afford latency here and this is required for further processing. IMap.get is called in jvm where cluster is started. Do we have a way to get the objects quickly irrespective of its size?

Answer (score 0):

This is partly the price you pay for `in-memory-format==OBJECT`
To confirm, try `in-memory-format==BINARY` and compare the difference.

Store and retrieve are slower with `OBJECT`, some queries will be faster. If you run enough of those queries the penalty is justified.

If you do `get(X)` and the value is stored deserialized (OBJECT), the following sequence occurs

- 1 - the object it serialized from object to `byte[]`
- 2 - the byte array is sent to the caller, possibly across the network
- 3 - the object is deserialized by the caller, `byte[]` to object.

If you change to store serialized (BINARY), step 1 isn't need.
If the caller is the same process, step 2 isn't needed.

If you can, it's worth upgrading (latest is 5.1.3) as there are some newer options that may perform better. See [this blog post](https://hazelcast.com/blog/comparing-serialization-options/) explaining.

You also don't necessarily have to return the entire object to the caller. A [read-only EntryProcessor](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/javadoc/com/hazelcast/core/ReadOnly.html) can extract part of the data you need to return across the network. A smaller network packet will help, but if the cost is in the serialization then the difference may not be remarkable.

Answer (score 0):

If you're retrieving a non-local map entry (either because you're using client-server deployment model, or an embedded deployment with multiple nodes so that some retrievals are remote), then a retrieval is going to require moving data across the network.  There is no way to move data across the network that isn't affected by object size; so the solution is to find a way to make the objects more compact.

You don't mention what serialization method you're using, but the default Java serialization is horribly inefficient ... any other option would be an improvement.  If your code is all Java, IdentifiedDataSerializable is the most performant.   See the following blog for some numbers:

https://hazelcast.com/blog/comparing-serialization-options/

Also, if your data is stored in BINARY format, then it's stored in serialized form (whatever serialization option you've chosen), so at retrieval time the data is ready to be put on the wire.  By storing in OBJECT form, you'll have to perform the serialization at retrieval time.  This will make your GET operation slower.  The trade-off is that if you're doing server-side compute (using the distributed executor service, EntryProcessors, or Jet pipelines), the server-side compute is faster if the data is in OBJECT format because it doesn't have to deserialize the data to access the data fields.  So if you aren't using those server-side compute capabilities, you're better off with BINARY storage format.

Finally, if your objects are large, do you really need to be retrieving the entire object?  Using the SQL API, you can do a SELECT of just certain fields in the object, rather than retrieving the entire object.  (You can also do this with Projections and the older Predicate API but the SQL method is the preferred way to do this).  If the client code doesn't need the entire object, selecting certain fields can save network bandwidth on the object transfer.